# How to convert a varchar value to datatype int in SQL Server 2008 with inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two lookup tables `MyProviders` and `MyGroups`. In my stored procedure, I have a temp table (replaced with an actual table for this example) with data. One column `EntityId` refers to either provider or a group. `EntityTypeId` tells me in that temp table if the entity is 1 = Provider or 2 = Group. `EntityId` can either have numeric `GroupId` or alphanumeric `ExternalProviderId`.

I want to check if there is any record in my temp table that has an invalid combination of `clientOid + entityid` from `myprovider` and `mygroup` table.

```
create table MyProviders 
(
    id int, 
    clientoid varchar(20), 
    externalproviderid varchar(20), 
    name varchar(25)
)

create table MyGroups 
(
    id int, 
    clientoid varchar(20), 
    name varchar(25)
)

create table MyJobDetails 
(
     clientoid varchar(20), 
     entityid varchar(20), 
     entitytypeid int, 
     entityname varchar(30)
)

insert into MyJobDetails values ('M.OID', 'MONYE', 1, 'Mark')
insert into MyJobDetails values ('M.OID', 2, 1, 'Lori')
insert into MyJobDetails values ('M.OID', 2, 2, 'Group 1')
insert into MyJobDetails values ('M.OID', 44444, 2, 'Group 2')

insert into MyProviders values (1, 'M.OID', 'MONY', 'Richard')
insert into MyProviders values (2, 'M.OID', '2', 'Mike')
insert into MyProviders values (3, 'M.OID', '3', 'Lori')

insert into MyGroups values (1, 'M.OID', 'Group 1')
insert into MyGroups values (2, 'M.OID', 'Group 2')
```

I tried the following query to determine if there is an invalid entity or not.

```
select 
    COUNT(*) 
from 
    MyJobDetails as jd 
where 
    not exists (select 1 
                from MyProviders as p 
                where p.ClientOID = jd.ClientOID 
                  and p.ExternalProviderID = CAST(jd.EntityId as varchar(20)) 
                  and jd.EntityTypeId = 1)
    and not exists (select 1 
                    from MyGroups as g 
                    where g.ClientOID = jd.ClientOID 
                      and g.Id = jd.EntityId 
                      and jd.EntityTypeId = 2)
```

This works as expected until I get an alphanumeric data in my temp table that doesn't exist in provider table. I get the following error message:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'MONYE' to data type int.

I have tried to update the solutions mentioned in other threads to use `IsNumeric` but it didn't work either. In this example, I need to return 1 for one invalid entry of `MONYE` which doesn't exist either in `MyProvider` or `MyGroup` table.

Also, if I can optimize the query in better way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

This is a **really bad design** in my opinion.

Since you're referencing one out of two tables, you cannot **enforce** referential integrity.

And having different datatypes for your keys makes things even more horrible.

I would use

- **two** separate foreign keys in `MyJobDetails` - one to `MyProvider` (`varchar(20)`) and another one to `MyGroup` (`int`)
- make them both nullable
- establish a **proper foreign key** relationship to the referenced table for each of those two

This way, both can be the **correct** datatype for each referenced table, and you won't need the `EntityTypeId` column anymore.

As a side note: whenever you use `Varchar` in SQL Server, whether you're defining a parameter, a variable, or using it in a `CAST` statement, I would recommend to **always** explicitly define a **length** for that `varchar`.

Or do you know what length this `varchar` in your conversion here is going to be?

```
CAST(jd.EntityId as varchar)
```

Use an explicit length - **always** - it's just a good, safe practice to employ:

```
CAST(jd.EntityId as varchar(15))
```

Comment: Thanks Marc for the response. I agree, this design is very poor, which I can't change at this time. But you made me think, and I guess easier solution for me would be to create temp table as per your suggestion and use the following query to fix it: `select COUNT(*) from MyJobDetails as jd 
where not exists (select 1 from MyProviders as p where p.ClientOID = jd.ClientOID and p.ExternalProviderID = jd.providerid and jd.EntityTypeId = 1)
and not exists (select 1 from MyGroups as g where g.ClientOID = jd.ClientOID and g.Id = jd.groupid and jd.EntityTypeId = 2)`

Answer (score 0):

In the second AND NOT EXISTS section you compare g.Id, an int, with jd.EntityId, a varchar. Cast the g.Id as a varchar.

```
and not exists (select 1 
                from #MyGroups as g 
                where g.ClientOID = jd.ClientOID 
                  and CAST(g.Id AS VARCHAR(20)) = jd.EntityId  
                  and jd.EntityTypeId = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select count(*)
from (
    select clientoid,entityid from #MyJobDetails where entitytypeid=1
    except
    select p.ClientOID ,convert(varchar(200),p.ExternalProviderID) from #MyProviders p inner join #MyJobDetails jd on p.ClientOID = jd.ClientOID and p.ExternalProviderID = CAST(jd.EntityId as varchar(20)) where jd.EntityTypeId = 1
    except
    select g.ClientOID,convert(varchar(200),g.Id) from #MyGroups g inner join #MyJobDetails jd on g.ClientOID = jd.ClientOID and g.Id = jd.EntityId where jd.EntityTypeId = 2
)a
```